# Programmatically create, load and run java file

Tags: java, class, junit, classloader, javac

Currently I have an existing JUnit test suite called `TestSuite.java`.

I then use a `BufferedWriter` and produce a new Java file named `TestSuiteMinimized.java`.

I then programmatically compile the file by using a process which runs a `javac` command with the necessary classpath.

The issue now is that I cannot seem to run this newly created Java file.

```
private static Map<String, String> runJavaFile(String filePath) {
    Class<?> test;
    try {
        test = Class.forName(getClassName(filePath), true, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Class not found in file: " + filePath);
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
        return null;
    }

    // Map from method name to failure trace.
    Map<String, String> runResultMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(test);
    for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
        runResultMap.put(failure.getDescription().getMethodName(), removeLineNumbersFromTrace(failure.getTrace()));
    }
    return runResultMap;
}
```

When I first run the program where only TestSuite.java exists and TestSuiteMinimized.java hasn't been created yet, I get a ClassNotFoundException:

```
Class not found in file: C:\Users\Wayway\workspace\Project1\src\TestSuiteMinimized.java
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestSuiteMinimized
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at Project1.runJavaFile(Project1.java:739)
    at Project1.mainMinimize(Project1.java:176)
    at Project1.main(Project1.java:105)
```

However, if I run the program again now that a TestSuiteMinimized.java has been written and compiled, this gets loaded and the ClassNotFoundException goes away. However, I am writing to TestSuiteMinimized.java in multiple iterations, and it appears that the new versions of TestSuiteMinimized.java aren't being run. Rather, only the first version of TestSuiteMinimized.java is ever loaded.

This appears to be a ClassLoader issue, but the above approach with Class.forname(...) does not seem to load the class.

What would be the correct approach? Thanks!

Comment: You're trying to run a Java program from another Java program, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, specifically it is a JUnit test suite that is being run in my Java program.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about using JUnit but the easiest way I found to do this is to export the class you're trying to run as an executable JAR file, and execute it via command line like so :

```
String cmd = "java - jar NAME OF YOUR PROGRAM.JAR";
try {
            //Execute the command
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            counter++;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The program you're calling needs to be in the same directory as the one calling it, or it needs to be a file path to the jar you're trying to run.

Like I said, I'm not sure about running JUnit files, but if you can export them as executable jars it should be the same idea.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did use Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd) before. In fact, I'm still using it to compile the Java file first. However, with the new approach, I need to run the class programmaticallly using JUnitCore.runClasses(...). This allows me to easily retrieve the failure output. The issue in particular is properly loading the class...